# Convert jsonObject to array in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have no idea about how to handle json, but I want to  convert `state_wise` json object into json array in c#. I want to loop through the `state_wise`

Json:

```
{
  "key_values": null,
  "total_values": {
    "active": "2543914",
    "confirmed": "16602456",
    "deaths": "189549",
    "deltaconfirmed": "344949",
    "deltadeaths": "2620",
    "deltarecovered": "220382",
    "lastupdatedtime": "24/4/2021 00:09:14",
    "migratedother": "6874",
    "recovered": "13862119",
    "state": "Total",
    "statecode": "TT",
    "statenotes": ""
  },
  "state_wise": {
    "Maharashtra": {
      "active": "691851",
      "confirmed": "4161676",
      "deaths": "63252",
      "deltaconfirmed": "66836",
      "deltadeaths": "773",
      "deltarecovered": "74045",
      "lastupdatedtime": "23/04/2021 21:15:15",
      "migratedother": "1781",
      "recovered": "3404792",
      "state": "Maharashtra",
      "statecode": "MH",
      "statenotes": "[Dec 16]:10,218 duplicate cases & other state cases removed from total cases.791 recovered cases also removed from total recovered cases while reconciling \n[Sep 9] :239 cases have been removed from the hospitalized figures owing to the removal of duplicates and change of addresses as per the original residence\n[Aug 15] : MH bulletin has reduced 819 confirmed cases in Mumbai and 72 confirmed cases from 'Other States' from the tally\n[Jun 16] : 1328 deceased cases have been retroactively added to MH bulletin.\n[Jun 20] : 69 deceased cases have been reduced based on state bulletin."
    },
    "Kerala": {
      "active": "178979",
      "confirmed": "1350502",
      "deaths": "5056",
      "deltaconfirmed": "28447",
      "deltadeaths": "27",
      "deltarecovered": "5663",
      "lastupdatedtime": "23/04/2021 19:32:13",
      "migratedother": "332",
      "recovered": "1166135",
      "state": "Kerala",
      "statecode": "KL",
      "statenotes": "Mahe native who expired in Kannur included in Kerala's deceased tally.\nSome non-covid deaths have also been reported in the bulletin.\nThese have been reduced from active count"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have control on changing the json?

Comment: Stating requirements is not the same as asking a question. Have you been able to research topics about working with json?

Answer (score -1):

first create a class with the property that you want to map.
then parse json to the class
at last you can use the class and it's property
like this :

class for mapping to it  :

```
    public class version
    {
        public string version_Number { set; get; }
    }
```

how to map  :

```
string uri = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/version";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
System.Console.WriteLine(response);
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<version>(response);
```